# GitHub: searching through older versions of files

Tags: git, github

I know that using GitHub I can search through all the current versions of my files in a repo. However, I would also like to search through the older versions of my repo files. For example, say, I used to have a function called get_info() in my code, but deleted it several versions ago, is it possible to search for get_info and find the code. If it is not possible using GitHub, is it possible from the git command line?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Mark Longair for showing how this can be done from the git command line. If it's not possible in GitHub it would be a great feature to have.

Comment: Dare I say... an "obvious" feature .. to have?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Currently, I don't believe it's possible to search within the complete history of a repository's code on the github website - the closest is just searching within the current code of a repository with the "code search" option on [this page](https://github.com/search).

However, from the command line, you can find any commits that introduced or removed lines mentioning `get_info` with the `-S` option to `git log`.  e.g.:

```
git log -Sget_info -p
```

(n.b. there should be no space between `-S` and the search term)

(also note: to search for more than one word, surround in `'`):

```
git log -S'get info' -p
```

So, at a minimum that should find the commit where the function was first introduced and the one that removed it.  I added the `-p` so you can also see the patches - if lots of commits introduced changes that mentioned the function that may be helpful.  If the function was only on another branch it might also be useful to use `--all` to search all branches.

[Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) points out in a comment below that git 1.7.4 will introduce the `-G` option as an alternative - this change is summarized in a recent blog post from Junio Hamano (git maintainer): http://gitster.livejournal.com/48191.html

Comment: Yes, I know I can search comments, but what about searching the code?

Comment: The -S option *does* look in the code - it finds any commits where `get_info` is contained in the diff that the commit introduces.  You might be getting confused with the `--grep` option, which searches the log messages.

Comment: @normski: And recent versions of git have added the similar `-G` option, which takes a regex instead of a fixed string.

Comment: @Jefromi: thanks for mentioning that - I've added that to the answer, hope that's OK.

Comment: @MarkLongair is it possible to search for more than one word?  how would you search for 'get info'

Comment: @Anthony Damico: yes, just quote the search string, e.g. `git log -S'get info' -p`

Comment: @MichaelChirico It has been a while and I am not sure what I did. I am going to delete the comment.

Comment: Is there any sort of UI that can help with this? Thanks!

Comment: "it finds any commits where get_info is contained in the diff that the commit introduces" - this is not quite accurate, -S finds any diff that changes the number of occurrences of the search string. To find any diff that contains a string, use -G.

Comment: this is really confusing, can you give a concrete example of how to search something please?

Answer (score 14):

```
git log -G'your text' -p --all
```

Note the following from the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt);

> [...] consider a commit with the following diff in the same file:
>
> ```diff
> +    return frotz(nitfol, two->ptr, 1, 0);
> ...
> -    hit = frotz(nitfol, mf2.ptr, 1, 0);
> ```
>
> While git log `-G"frotz\(nitfol"` will show this commit, git log `-S"frotz\(nitfol" --pickaxe-regex` will not (because the number of occurrences of that string did
> not change).

Kudos both Mark and Cascabel for pointing in the right direction

Comment: this worked for me where the accepted answer came short! thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in the Github web UI.  Github may download the file if it's too big or unsupported, may open it in a new tab if your browser can render the file, or may display it in-line. Here's two ways:

1. Go to the repo and choose the branch you want to view history for

### Method 1

2. Navigate to the folder your file is in.
3. Click on 'History', currently on the right side, upper area. [image: Underlines the 'History' button on the github web UI–that does not look like a link until you hover over the text.]
4. From here, click on... what I'm just going to call the 'code paper' icon. It's currently positioned to the right of the commit sha button and has a label of, 'View at this point in the history.' [image: Arrow points at the 'code paper' icon on the github web UI.]
5. Click "View Raw" (If you skipped step 2, drill in until you get to the file you need) to get at the code you need.

### Method 2

2. Click on the 'nnn commits' text. Currently on the right side. [image: Arrow points at the '113 commits' link in the github web UI–that does not look like a link until you hover over the text.]
3. Click on the 'code' button. This one currently looks like two carets '<>' and has an label of, 'Browse the repository at this point in the history.' [image: Arrow points at the 'code' button with the left and right caret imagery in the github web UI.]
4. Drill in and find the file you need, to get at the code.

Method 1 seems more efficient when I know what file I need, but not which commit to go back to. Method 2 is faster when I know exactly which time window or commit to look at, but maybe not where the file lives.

---

Disclaimer: UIs change frequently.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the initial question of viewing files from your repositories history directly from the GitHub online GUI, take the following steps. In your repo:

1. View previous commits.
   [image: View previous commits.]
2. Select the branch ID for a commit that corresponds to the point in history you wish to view.
   [image: Select the branch ID]
3. In the top left, select **Browse Files** to view all files at that point in time.
   [image: Select Browse Files]