# In GitHub, how do I search for "RecoverCompact" in "CPubKey::RecoverCompact"

Tags: c++, git, github

I'm searching GitHub [for a given definition of](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/key.cpp#L446) "RecoverCompact", and I keep getting results that were checked in from the first release.

I realized my mistake is that GitHub doesn't search the partial text because it sees "CPubKey::RecoverCompact" as a single string, when in my case I don't know which object this is in.

- Why is it that I can search for some instances of "RecoverCompact" and not others? (namely old versions?)
- Assuming this has to do with how the method is declared, what is this declaration format called? (Global? .. I'm not a C++ developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [search `RecoverCompact` in that same repo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?q=RecoverCompact&ref=cmdform), you can see [its declaration](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/42a12f22d6b644fcd879da23f6e56c310eb9985f/src/key.h#L159-L160) in the [`CPubKey` class](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/42a12f22d6b644fcd879da23f6e56c310eb9985f/src/key.h#L39-L40)

```
// Recover a public key from a compact signature.
bool RecoverCompact(const uint256 &hash, const std::vector<unsigned char>& vchSig);
```

To search through older version, you would have to clone the repo and use [`git log -G`](http://gitster.livejournal.com/48191.html), as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705617/6309).

Comment: The problem is that it goes to an old version of the branch.  And for every search I have to click through to get the master.

It seems that anything done after the refactoring (changing the method signature) isn't searchable, and is the basis for my question.

Comment: @makerofthings7 the key.h file mentioned is only from 3 days ago, not exactly old. However, if you are looking for a refactoring, then it is best to to a `git log -SRecoverCompact` in a local clone, rather than relying on a web-based search.