# Analysis of rippled Code on Github ? Need help, lack of documentations ( specially define and macros)

Tags: c++, github, boost, open-source, ripple

I am working on code produced by a company called Ripple that provides cross-currency payment solutions.

I am currently analyzing the code of their daemon server [available on Github](https://github.com/ripple/rippled).

I might not be the first to arrive to this conclusion, but it is extremely difficult to not get lost working on someone else's large project. Although a documentation is provided, the code still does not seems understandable to me if you aren't one of the creators.

One main difficulty is that the code refers to external libraries and sometimes it feels impossible to know where to look to learn what a function does or which value a variable contains.

---

Simple example from my question of the moment:

---

I'm starting with the main.cpp file (because I assume that is what is launched when the program starts) and I have these lines:

```
#if defined(BEAST_LINUX) || defined(BEAST_MAC) || defined(BEAST_BSD)
#include <sys/resource.h>
#endif
```

I searched for a week now but I can't find what `BEAST_LINUX` is for.

(It is a redundant problem where macros and preprocessos instructions are called very frequently which refers to `#define` that refers to `#define` and so on, and documentation can rarely be found on the net).

Additionally, is there a quick way to discover where a variable is declared in a GitHub repository, especially when it is declared in another file ?

Answer (score 4):

```
#if defined(BEAST_LINUX) || defined(BEAST_MAC) || defined(BEAST_BSD)
#include <sys/resource.h>
#endif
```

Let me walk you through how I would reason about this code:

First, I see that it's going to sometimes include `sys/resource.h` and sometimes not include it. The `<>` tells me that it's a system header. So this is code to decide whether or not to include a particular system header.

Second, I see that the test is for macros that differ in that one says `LINUX`, one `MAC`, and one `BSD`. I know these are platforms. And the test is an or.

So, now I can conclude that if a define associated with one of three platforms is set, then we include a particular system header.

Punching `sys/resource.h` into my favorite search engine, I find that it's part of the [Single UNIX Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysresource.h.html). And I notice that all three platforms mentioned in the macro have a UNIX heritage.

So, in conclusion, the code appears to include a SUS header on those platforms that are expected to have that particular header. In particular, not on Windows which isn't going to have it.

By the way, I'd suggest cloning the git repository onto your own machine so you can use local search tools on it. If you're going to be analyzing a lot of code, it's worth setting up an environment that can hold code and let you compile and analyze it and then learn how to use its search and navigation tools to get around the code quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm one of the developers of `rippled`. As the other answer alludes, this is a macro that is set to a non-zero value when the code is being compiled on a Linux platform; if it is, then it causes the preprocessor to include the specific header.

This define was, originally, in a library named Beast. Large parts of that library were moved out of Beast and into the Ripple source, to help facilitate inclusion of Beast's awesome websocket and http routines into Boost.

If you are working under Windows, there is a Visual Studio project which, when loaded, makes discovering symbols and code call graphs pretty easy using the tools built-in to Visual Studio.

I also have a Doxygen build, which produces nice documentation of classes and comments, along with a cross-reference. I'll see about making it available publicly over the web.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a macro

```
#if (defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64))
  #define       BEAST_WIN32 1
  #define       BEAST_WINDOWS 1
#elif defined (BEAST_ANDROID)
  #undef        BEAST_ANDROID
  #define       BEAST_ANDROID 1
#elif defined (LINUX) || defined (__linux__)
#define BEAST_LINUX 1
```

defined in this source [Beast: An amazing cross platform library](https://github.com/stellar/stellard/tree/master/src/beast) in this file [PlatformConfig.h](https://github.com/stellar/stellard/blob/67eabb2217bdfa9a6ea317f62338fb6bca458c90/src/beast/beast/config/PlatformConfig.h). This is an old source however, the new library doesn't contain this define anymore. This new library is located here [Beast](https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast), also submitted to Boost.

You can search specific repository for code by using Github search, however, it only works on latest file versions. To do a search for all file versions you'll need to do it from command line, as explained here [GitHub: searching through older versions of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705517/github-searching-through-older-versions-of-files). There's no fast way to search for variable or macro definition, except if your IDE supports go to definition functionality.

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for.

Comment: I am also seeking to  learn how to search more that to learn how to use these libraries . How did you know it were on "stellar" deposit and specially the PlatformConfig.h file (there are a lot of include of headers at the beginning of each file I look at).

Comment: I searched `stellar` repo for "BEAST_LINUX", then did Ctrl+F and searched for "#define", then clicked through results until I saw the definition. I don't think you will find any good docs on 2013 version of Beast, but you might have luck in contacting the author and asking for it.

Comment: So, you linked to Stellar's copy of Beat which is out of date. The newest version of Beast is here:
https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast/
Note, I am the author.

Comment: @VinnieFalco i did provide a link to your current repository :) Should have made it more obvious, though

Comment: Can't understand why the downvotes, since OP said that my answer is what he was looking for. At least provide the reason of the downvote, since I can't improve without reasonable feedback