# github page: how to search for a text in previous commited work

Tags: github

Say you wrote in a file the text: `save_as` and committed your work (call it commit_A). Later, you decided to remove it and committed your work (call it commit_B).

Question: how can you search in the **github page** for the text: `save_as` and find it in commit_A? It doesn't show anything even if I add `fork:true`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of this question [GitHub: searching through older versions of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705517/github-searching-through-older-versions-of-files)

Check the answer by Mark Longair, as his shows how this is possible with the command line.

tl:dr: `git log -S'get info' -p`