# Accessing older versions of files on github?

Tags: github

I did notice this [10-year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705517/github-searching-through-older-versions-of-files), but I still wanted to ask if there is any new method in the past 10 years for seeing older versions of files on github. I see if I go through the commit history that I can browse the *entire* repository at a particular point in time, but my file of interest is in a folder with enough other files that I get a "Sorry, we had to truncate this directory to 1,000 files. 293 entries were omitted from the list." warning, and am unable to access it...

I can click to my file of interest and see diffs, but I really just want to see that entire file on github as of a particular commit.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Click on the commit, then click on the triple dots, and then click view file.