# GIT: How to search through older versions of a file and list all versions that match the search criteria?

Tags: bash, git

I have a repo that contains a certain file. I need to create a git script that searches through all the previous versions of this file and lists the commit SHAs that contain a specific string.
I want to have a list of all the commits that in their version that string exists.

The best answer I could find is here (but not good enough): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705617/4441211
This solution is not good enough because this only finds where there was a change (i.e the search term was added or removed). Does anybody have a better idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look for a pattern `<pattern>` in a file `<path/to/file>` within a commit `<commit>` : use `git grep`

```sh
git grep -e <pattern> <commit> -- <path/to/file>
```

Check `git help grep` for more details : many options are copied of the original `grep` command (`-l` to only list file names, `-q` to drop output ...)

---

If your intention is to scan all commits looking for a string (not just the commits where a change occured) :

- `git rev-list HEAD` will give you the list of all commits in the ancestry of your active branch,
- write a loop to repeatedly call `git grep` on these commits.

For example :

```sh
git rev-list HEAD | while read sha; do
    git grep -q -e <pattern> $sha -- <path/to/file> && echo $sha
done
```

Comment: This works great with just one small modification: instead of `git rev-list HEAD` I used `git rev-list --all` in order to scan all the commits in the repo. Thanks a lot this works perfectly!